# How can I call my array to my main class?

Tags: java

I have one class called DVD collection and another one called movies. The method with the array that I'm trying to return looks like this:

```
public class DVDCollection
{
  public static DVD[] collection;
  public static void searchForDVD( String DVD[], String a) {
    System.out.println("What DVD would you like to search for?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    a = scan.nextLine();
    int N = DVD.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
      for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
      if (DVD[j-1].compareTo(DVD[j]) > 0)
      change(DVD, j, j-1);
    else break;
    for (int i = 0; i < DVD.length; i++) {
      System.out.print(DVD[i] + a);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to call it from my main method like so:

```
public class Movies
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    DVDCollection movies = new DVDCollection();
    movies.searchForDVD(DVD);
  }
}
```

But it gives me an error saying cannot find symbol - variable DVD

So what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

You're calling

```
movies.searchForDVD(DVD);
```

but there is no `DVD` variable defined in the main method. And BTW, even if there was one, the `searchForDVD()` method takes two arguments, and not just one.

Also note that the `searchForDVD()` method is static. So you don't need any instance of DVDCollection to call it. Instead of

```
DVDCollection movies = new DVDCollection();
movies.searchForDVD(...);
```

you should use

```
DVDCollection.searchForDVD(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main method when calling the `searchForDVD` method you must pass it an array of strings for the dvds along with the name of the dvd as a string.

At the moment you are passing the variable DVD which you have not declared anywhere in the main method.

Code in main method should be:

```
String[] dvds = new String[] {"firstDVD","secondDVD","thirdDVD");
String movie = "secondDVD";
DVDCollection.searchForDVD(dvds,movie);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling DVD several times in this code. I believe the mistake here is the variable name.

You have defined `public static DVD[] collection;` which is an array of DVD objects called collection. The variable name is `collection` and that is what you need to use when referencing the variable.

ie: `collection.length` instead of DVD.length.

When you say `public static DVD[] collection;`, you are telling the compiler to create you a public, static Array of DVD objects called collection. At some point this array would need to be initialized. Arrays are initialized in the following format:

```
DVD[] collection = new DVD[];
```

or
    String[] arrayOfStrings = {"a","b","c","d"};

Another problem is that your method is defined as follows:

```
public static void searchForDVD( String DVD[], String a)
```

This method is requiring two arguments, not one. If you are trying to require a String[] array called "DVD" then you should declare as follows:

```
public static void searchForDVD( String[] DVD, String a)
```

That declaration says this method takes an array of strings and we'll call it DVD and another String which will be called a.

Make sure to note what your variable type is and what your variable name is.
The type tells java what to expect in the variable, the name is how you access it.

```
String myString = "string data";
```

String is the type. myString is the variable name. "string data" is the value assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

**problem 1**

```
movies.searchForDVD(DVD);
```

the parameter `DVD` is not defined.

**problem 2**

`public static void searchForDVD(...)` is a **static** method of class `DVDCollection` you should call it `DVDCollection.searchForDVD(...)` you don't need the `movie` object.

Answer (score 0):

What makes sense to me is something like:

```
public class Movies
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        DVDCollection movies = new DVDCollection();

        //create an Add function inside DVDCollection which reads lines from a text file into collection
        movies.Add("list_of_movies.txt");

        // no arguments are needed here imo, just have it print to user to ask for a DVD to search and then search the collection
        movies.searchForDVD();
    }
}

public class DVDCollection
{
    public DVD[] collection;
    public void Add(string file)
    {
      // parse file and add contents to collection
    }
    public void searchForDVD()
    {
        System.out.println("What DVD would you like to search for?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = scan.nextLine();
        int N = DVD.length;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
           for (int j = i; j > 0; j--)
              if (DVD[j-1].compareTo(DVD[j]) > 0)
                 change(DVD, j, j-1);
              else break;
        for (int i = 0; i < DVD.length; i++)
        {
           System.out.print(DVD[i] + a);
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
}
```